# Why is speed measured along the line of sight (LOS) a factor $\sqrt{3} $ smaller for randomly distributed velocities?

Tags: cosmology, speed-of-light, velocity, galaxies, redshift

I encountered [this problem](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26490/) from Introduction to Modern Cosmology by Andrew Liddle.

I had the exact same doubt as the OP of that question had, and the first answer makes sense but I don't understand why "For randomly distributed velocities, the speed V$_{||}$ you measure along your line of sight (LOS) is a factor $\sqrt{3} $ smaller, i.e. ∼350kms$^{−1}$."

How to derive this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RMS velocity has three components that add in quadrature
$$ v_{\rm rms}^2 = \sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2 + \sigma_z^2\ ,$$
where $\sigma_i$ are the RMS velocities along the orthogonal coordinate axes.

If the velocity field is isotropic then we expect the RMS to be the same in any direction and so $\sigma_x = v_{\rm rms}/\sqrt{3}$, where the x-axis could be your line of sight.